# Retrieve the name and contents of attachments for an e-mail that has been sent

Tags: laravel, email, attachment, swiftmailer

In Laravel, I'm looking for a way to retrieve the attachments (if any) for an e-mail that has been sent and then store that attachment on the filesystem.

I have created a new listener for the `Illuminate\Mail\Events\MessageSent` event and I'm currently fetching the attachment name, but I don't know how to fetch the contents of the attachment for later storage:

```
public function handle($event)
{
    $subject = $event->message->getSubject();
    $body = $event->message->getBody();
    $recipient = array_keys($event->message->getTo())[0];

    $attachments = [];

    foreach ($event->message->getChildren() as $child) {
        $attachments[]  = [
            'name' => str_replace('attachment; filename=', null, $child->getHeaders()->get('content-transfer-encoding')->getFieldBody()),
            'contents' => '' // ?
        ];
    }
}
```

Does anybody know how to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should filter message children by Swift_Attachment::class and you can get the attachment content with getBody(). You may have to call getBody() twice due to a [swiftmailer issue](https://github.com/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/issues/1289).
Filename, content type and body are easily accessible from the swift attachment object.

```
foreach (collect($event->message->getChildren())->whereInstanceOf(Swift_Attachment::class) as $attachment) {
    $attachment->getBody(); // issue workaround
    $attachments[]  = [
        'name' => $attachment->getFilename(),
        'contentType' => $attachment->getContentType(), 
        'contents' => $attachment->getBody(),
    ];
}
```